# probability density function of a sample mean

Tags: probability, statistics

I am being asked to find the probability density function of the sample mean based on a random sample of two cases of the given distribution table. How do I go about solving this. I have made no progress yet because I'm not sure where to start.

[Given problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CixNM.png)

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax and see [MathJax tutorial](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189). Please [don't use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to those who use screen readers. Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for information on writing a good question. People will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include an explanation of your own attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If two cases means two samples, then 
\begin{equation}
 \bar{X} = \frac{Z_1 + Z_2}{2}
\end{equation}
where 
\begin{equation}
 Z_1 \sim Z
\end{equation}
and 
\begin{equation}
 Z_2 \sim Z
\end{equation}
All the possible outcomes of $\bar{X}$ are easily enumerated as 
\begin{equation}
 \bar{X} \in \lbrace \frac{1+1}{2}; \frac{1+3}{2};\frac{1+5}{2};\frac{3+3}{2};\frac{3+5}{2};\frac{5+5}{2}\rbrace
\end{equation}
Now you could get the probability distribution function

Comment: Thank you very much!